# Group TCP or UDP protocols and order them by character numbers in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I need to make a menu in powershell that groups TCP or UDP Protocols when we write them in the script. Also I need the posibility in the menu to order them by character numbers. Currently I have done this, but it has a lot of mistakes. Sorry for the variable names and texts in spanish :(

```
function mostrarMenu 
{ 
     param ( 
           [string]$Titulo = 'Ejercicio 4' 
     ) 
     cls 
     Write-Host "================ $Titulo================" 
      
     
     Write-Host "1) Agrupar por protocolo" 
     Write-Host "2) Ordenarlos" 
     Write-Host "S) Presiona 'S' para salir"
}

do
{ 
     mostrarMenu 
     $input = Read-Host "En este ejercicio podremos contar los servicios de \etc\services. Elige una opcion" 
     switch ($input) 
     { 
           '1' { 
                cls 
                $elige = Read-Host "Pon TCP o UDP"
Get-Content -Path "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\services" | 
Select-String -Pattern $elige | Group-Object -Property {$_ -like "*$elige*"}
           } '2' { 
                cls 
                get-childitem | sort-object -property length
           } 's' { 
                return 
           }  
     } 
     pause 
} 
until ($input -eq 's')
```

Comment: When you say "order them by character numbers", what exactly do you mean? Can you show some examples of input values for which is doesn't work as intended?

Comment: The TCP and UDP protocols have a service name, the idea is to order all of them by the number of letter that they have.

Example:

discard
systat
quotd
echo

Comment: Here in the first Gyazo, its what the script shows when I introduce TCP on the variable: https://gyazo.com/bc504c637b6ba242fe66966e68f71084 . The first mistake that there is here is that if I write something that isnt TCP or UDP it shows me the TCP one but I would like to put an alert saying that the service doest exists or something like that.

Also when I try to order them appears this https://gyazo.com/8efd28d6b0149eb33adcb42c676a77b2 . And I would like to appear what I wrote in the first commentary.

Also sorry for the mistakes, I am really newbie in PowerShell and its a school project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following to group by protocol and then apply a sort by service name length:

```
(Get-Content C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\services) -notmatch '^#' -ne '' |
    Group-Object { $_ -replace '^.*\d+/(\w{3}).*$','$1'} | Foreach-Object {
        $_.Group | Sort-Object {
            ($_ -replace '\s+\d+/\w{3}.*$').Length
        }
    }
```

`-notmatch '^#' -ne ''` removes empty and commented lines from the output.

`^.*\d+/(\w{3}).*$` matches each line that contains the `PortNumber/Protocol` format. Everything on those matched lines is replaced. Capture group `1` is the protocol. The matched text is replaced by just the protocol `$1`. The grouping occurs based on that value.

`\s+\d+/\w{3}.*$` matches everything after the service name. That matched text is replaced. The remaining service name is then sorted.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I think that its what I need :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is wrong?

Your line

```
Get-Content -Path "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\services" | 
Select-String -Pattern $elige | Group-Object -Property {$_ -like "*$elige*"}
```

runs just fine grouping all of the same protocol (I assume elige is spanish for protocol) together (except for when the same characters show up elsewhere in the line). What comes out is a single object whose `Group` property holds an array of all of the corresponding lines.

Maybe what you mean is to group first? It sounds like maybe you want to group them by protocol and, within the group, sort alphabetically by name?

```
$groupedContent = Get-Content -Path "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\services" | # content line-by-line
     ForEach-Object {
         $newline = $_ -split ' ' | ForEach-Object Trim | Where-Object {$_} # convert line into an array
         Write-Output $newline -NoEnumerate
     } |
     Sort-Object {$_[0]} | # sort by name
     Group-Object {($_[1] -split '/')[-1]} # group by protocol

# retrieve chosen protocol (tcp or udp)
$groupedContent | Where-Object Name -EQ $elige | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Group
```

I just also want to point out that `get-childitem | sort-object -property length` is sorting the files and folders in the current directory. This seems off of what you were asking and I neither speak spanish nor tried to translate it so I will leave it up to your judgement if that is what you meant to do.

Comment: The meaning of "elige" is select, so, the idea its to select what protocol I want to see, TCP or UDP, but yes, this answer is what I need. I'll try it when I arrive home, anyways thank you.

Comment: Also sorry for answering you too late, it was nighttime in my country xD